# Use non-templated version of class as parent

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates

I am working on porting a project from C# to C++ and am having an issue when using templates, I need to have both a non-templated and a templated version of a class with one parented to another, ie:

```
class DataBuffer // Holds generic databuffer functions (getting size in bytes etc)
{
public:
    int32 getVal() { return 10; }
};

template <typename T>
class DataBuffer<T> : public DataBuffer // Able to retrieve data as a type...
{
public:
    int32 getSizeOfT() { return sizeof(T); }
};
```

I have methods that accept any type of DataBuffer as a parameter, so templating the entire class is not possible, is there any way of doing this without renaming the base class?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
This code does not compile, and throws the following error at compile time:

```
error C2989: 'DataBuffer' : class template has already been declared as a non-class template
```

Comment: You can't create more than one class with the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way of doing so. I think the relevant portion of the standard is:

> A class template shall not have the same name as any other template,
>   class, function, object, enumeration, enumerator, namespace, or type
>   in the same scope (3.3), except as specified in (14.5.4). Except that
>   a function template can be overloaded either by (non-template)
>   functions with the same name or by other function templates with the
>   same name (14.8.3), a template name declared in namespace scope or in
>   class scope shall be unique in that scope.

However, the methods that should accept every type of `DataBuffer` could be made template too, so that inheriting from a common base would become unnecessary.

Comment: I have decided to modify the databuffer class to only have templated methods, this way i can continue to use my functions/methods as they were.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, a class template can't have the same name as a non-template.

You will have to rename either the base class or the template.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to give the class and the class template different names or put them into different namespaces: classes and class templates cannot have exactly the same name.